# How to run Table_Print gem as stand alone gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Working with a rails app and I want to utilize the [table_print gem](http://tableprintgem.com/) but I am not permitted to install a new gem into the gemfile. I see that there is a standalone version I should be able to install directly on my machine but I am not sure how to get it to work.

When I call `tp Invoice.all` I get the following error in return.

> NoMethodError: undefined method `tp' for main:Object

I've tried creating an .irbrc file with variations of the following code, but no joy.

```
# Outside rails
$ irb
> require 'table_print'
> tp array_of_objects, options

# Inside rails, the gem has already been required by your Gemfile so all you need to do is
$ rails c
> tp array_of_objects, options
```

Has anyone gotten the standalone version of table_print to work with rails c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

passing array directly into tp argument:

```
 ➩ ➩  irb
2.0.0-p645 :002 > require 'table_print'
 => true
2.0.0-p645 :003 > tp [{id: 1, first_name: "Tim", last_name: "Thing", email: "test@example.com", dob: "1985-01-01" },  {id: 2, first_name: "Rob", last_name: "Roberts", email: "test@example.com", dob: "1985-01-01"}, {id: 3, first_name: "Nancy", last_name: "Name", email: "test@example.com", dob: "1985-01-01"}]
ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | EMAIL            | DOB
---|------------|-----------|------------------|-----------
1  | Tim        | Thing     | test@example.com | 1985-01-01
2  | Rob        | Roberts   | test@example.com | 1985-01-01
3  | Nancy      | Name      | test@example.com | 1985-01-01
 => 0.000762
2.0.0-p645 :004 >
```

Or saving the array as a variable:

```
 ➩ ➩  irb
2.0.0-p645 :002 > require 'table_print'
 => true
2.0.0-p645 :004 > object = [{id: 1, first_name: "Tim", last_name: "Thing", email: "test@example.com", dob: "1985-01-01" },  {id: 2, first_name: "Rob", last_name: "Roberts", email: "test@example.com", dob: "1985-01-01"}, {id: 3, first_name: "Nancy", last_name: "Name", email: "test@example.com", dob: "1985-01-01"}]
=> [{:id=>1, :first_name=>"Tim", :last_name=>"Thing", :email=>"test@example.com", :dob=>"1985-01-01"}, {:id=>2, :first_name=>"Rob", :last_name=>"Roberts", :email=>"test@example.com", :dob=>"1985-01-01"}, {:id=>3, :first_name=>"Nancy", :last_name=>"Name", :email=>"test@example.com", :dob=>"1985-01-01"}]
2.0.0-p645 :005 > tp object
 ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | EMAIL            | DOB
 ---|------------|-----------|------------------|-----------
 1  | Tim        | Thing     | test@example.com | 1985-01-01
 2  | Rob        | Roberts   | test@example.com | 1985-01-01
 3  | Nancy      | Name      | test@example.com | 1985-01-01
 => 0.001
```

Without the full trace of the error this is all the help I can give. Hope it helps!

-the NoMethodError makes me think table_print doesn't like the ActiveRecord::Relation you're passing it.  maybe try passing `Invoice.all.map(&:attributes)` to tp

Comment: Getting back `LoadError: cannot load such file -- table_print` when I enter it in on line :002. I don't get back the `=> true`

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the gem installed in the right directory.  Try uninstalling the gem and then reinstalling it globally,  That will allow you to access it in any directory on your comp.

Comment: I think you caught my mistake. I'm trying to run rails c AND use the global installed gem. Is this possible?